# eclipse Custom Incremental Build Process

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I just want to tap into the eclipse build process (java projects), where that will do some custom validations and processing when a relevant class file (eg. A class with a special custom annotation is touched) ?

-Malinga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write a plug-in that uses the `org.eclipse.core.resources.builders` extension point to declare your own incremental builder.

See the Eclipse help: [Incremental project builders](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_builders.htm)