# Execute Eclipse Plugin when class is compiled

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, compilation

Is it somehow possible to execute an Eclipse plugin when running a Java programm? So far I only know how to add buttons or menu entries but my aim is to automatically run the plugin when the user compiles a class.

**Edit to avoid confusion**

My general aim is to parse text. So far, so good. Therefore I will (probably) use Abstrac Syntax Tree.

But my actual problem is that I want to do this *automatically* when the user starts the building process.

(I don't want the user to manally select my plugin when building, but rather "automatically participate" in the buld process (without affecting it).

Comment: Do you mean you want the plugin to participate in a project build process - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141311/eclipse-custom-incremental-build-process/20142707#20142707

Comment: @greg-449: I'm not quite sure. My aim is to parse the processed classes. Is this possible to achieve with an incremental project builder without affecting the regular building process?

Comment: The Eclipse JDT plugins already provide APIs to access the parse tree for the code - see the [JDT Programmer's Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_int.htm&cp=3_0)

Comment: @greg-449: I've made an edit to my original post to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the [org.eclipse.ui.startup](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_startup.html) identifier as an extension point.

Under "Extension Element Details" you have to select your StartupClass which implements [org.eclipse.ui.IStartup](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IStartup.html). Inside the method *earlyStartup()* you can specify any actions that should happen right after workspace/plugin startup.

(For my case I chose to use an [IResourceChangeListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResourceChangeListener.html) to determine when changes are made in the project. From that I can build on my other aims.)